# Squares after whitespace (Labels: -Area-Undefined Area-WebKit WebKit-Fonts)

Tags: html, google-chrome, css

Im getting a strange behavior in chrome that it creates squares after whitespace IE 

`Price: 123234` but this is not after all whitespaces on the site just in situations when i got two strings like Price: and then add the price in my code.

you can se the issues i got here 
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108926

I posted this question on the google chrome bugglist and i think somebody placed it in the category of (Labels: -Area-Undefined Area-WebKit WebKit-Fonts), its been like 3 weeks now so i dont expect anybody to answer that question so i thought i would try my luck here. anybody had the same?

Comment: Can you reproduce your bug in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please

Comment: probably not, im using html5 and css3. its really hard to reproduce it outside my project. there is a link tho in the issue i addressed to google, so maybe using chromes developertool can do the trick? but i got two sites that behave like this and its only in the latest version of chrome to, never had this issue before.

Comment: Ok, I have tried to reproduce with the code in the link provided but I could not. Unless someone has come across this before then I am not sure how much help you will be able to get without a reproduction. I have noticed Chrome seems to be getting more buggy as it advances.

Comment: Thanks for trying.. Your name = How I feel thinking of this issue :)

Comment: Could you add your HTML anyway where this occurs? And maybe the relevant CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to be a bugg with their latest release (it worked before it) and how they handle -webkit-font, in my specfic case it was

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

removing that line fixed my issues. i think its anything with -webkit-font, i use a lot of -webkit for backgrounds and other stuff and that works great..